# Function to stop scheme for a certain time

Tags: time, scheme, delay

does anyone know a Scheme function that delays yours program for a certain time?
I know the most languages have a function where you say for how many time you want that the program must wait, but I can't find it in Scheme.

I know the "delay" function in Scheme but that's not what I want, it only gives you a promise but don't stop running you program for a few seconds.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the interpreter being used (it's implementation-dependent). For instance, in Racket you can call the `sleep` procedure:

```
(display "Hello ") (sleep 2) (display "World!")
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/threads.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._sleep%29%29):

> `(sleep [secs]) → void?` Causes the current thread to sleep until at least secs seconds have passed after it starts sleeping. A zero value for secs simply acts as a hint to allow other threads to execute. The value of secs can be a non-integer to request a sleep duration to any precision; the precision of the actual sleep time is unspecified.